# Excel drop-down list data and values

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have a large Excel(Office 365) spreadsheet that uses drop down controls so the user can easily populate the cell with set values.

When you click on the cell the user can pick a value from the drop down.  The drop down data is defined in another sheet and looks like this:

```
Sedan
Pickup Truck
Hatchback
SUV
```

But because these are getting imported into a SQL Server database, I need the actual values to be IDs:

> 0, 1, 2, 3

Is there a way to let the user pick from the human readable text values, but have Excel store the number ID values?

Thanks!

Comment: you create a `vlookup` beside the drop-won column to get the ID's of each input?

Comment: @Gangula No I didn't do that, is that what you are asking if I did? Thanks!

Comment: @Gangula Ok I looked up `vlookup` and I think I know what you mean...